# Calling a function based on string stored in an array

Tags: vba, excel

I want to run a loop that will call a user-defined function which has the exact same name as the element in an array. I have defined 4 different functions by the names "India", "UK", "USA", and "Japan".

```
Countries = Array(India, UK, USA, Japan)

For i = 0 To UBound(Countries)

'{call the function named "India" when i = 0}  
'{call the function named "UK" when i = 1}  
'{call the function named "USA" when i = 2}  
'{call the function named "Japan" when i = 3}


Next i
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve this? Please excuse me if the code formatting is incorrect. Thank you.

Comment: [Application.Run Method (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197132.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    For i = 0 To 3
        Select Case i
        Case 0
            Call India
        Case 1
            Call UK
        Case 2
            Call USA
        Case 3
            Call JAPAN
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

or:

```
Sub luxation()
    Countries = Array("India", "UK", "USA", "JAPAN")
    For i = 0 To 3
        Application.Run (Countries(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Tested with:

```
Sub India()
    MsgBox "India"
End Sub
Sub UK()
    MsgBox "UK"
End Sub
Sub USA()
    MsgBox "USA"
End Sub
Sub JAPAN()
    MsgBox "Japan"
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use callbyname to call things in class modules (or any other object).

Executes a method of an object, or sets or returns a property of an object.

**Syntax**

```
CallByName(object, procname, calltype,[args()])
```

**OR**

Call a vbscript stored in a string (ie a macro). Any app can have macros with 6 lines of code. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adcae113-4758-481a-a367-60d5d14d97d6/this-is-how-to-turn-vbs-and-js-files-into-exe-files-from-the-command-line-without-third-party-tools?forum=scripting